# Is there a way to reduce unnecessary CSS code from this container/textbox example?

Tags: html, css

Is there any simple way that I could efficiently make use of one textbox/container and use it for all of my pages?

I am new to HTML/CSS, so I had been duplicating the same code every time in CSS for the same style, but just different positioning.

Is there a way I could make just one container & one textbox in CSS that gives a fixed style, but the positioning could be changed?

```css
.container-2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 230px;
  left: 1166px;
}

.textbox1 {
  background: rgb(172, 221, 232);
  border: 3.5px solid black;
  width: 900px;
  height: 215px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 467px;
  top: 385px;
  margin: 0;
}

.textbox2 {
  background: rgb(45, 110, 125);
  border: 3.5px solid black;
  width: 900px;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1625px;
  top: 71px;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 550px;
  left: 1166px;
}

.textbox3 {
  background: rgb(45, 110, 125);
  border: 3.5px solid black;
  width: 900px;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1625px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 0.9;
}

.textbox4 {
  background: rgb(172, 221, 232);
  border: 3.5px solid black;
  width: 900px;
  height: 290px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 467px;
  top: 630px;
  margin: 0;
}

.textbox1 p {
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.textbox2 p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  bottom: 62px;
  left: 370px;
}

.textbox3 p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  bottom: 64px;
  left: 150px;
}

.textbox4 p {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 302px;
  left: 90px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="textbox1">
  <p>#
    <p>
      <em>#</em>
</section>


<section class="container-2">
  <section class="textbox2">
    <p>#
      <p>
  </section>
</section>


<section class="container-3">
  <section class="textbox3">
    <p>#
      <p>
  </section>
</section>


<section class="textbox4">
  <p>'#'</p>
</section>
```

Comment: I saw that you didn't close properly some HTML tags by using `</TAG_NAME>`

Comment: Thanks, I just added the </section> tag @LaaouatniAnas

Comment: is the problem that you have multiple pages but same css?

Comment: I am using the same CSS for 3 pages, and all these textbox's have different positioning (but same styles).

Comment: you can use multiple classes `class="textbox3 custom3"`

Comment: What does that mean? - How would I apply that?

Comment: Would that reduce the unnecessary CSS?

Comment: it means that you can use the same css in all 3 pages, but you will create a style tag that is only accessible on the same page and create a new class with the extra css, and then add the element with 2 classes

Comment: no is not reduce, so maybe use `,` like this `textbox1, textbox2 {}` or use a default class `textbox` then inside the specific page use textbox1, textbox2, textbox3

Comment: In your first example, this works with keeping the style which is good, but it messes up the positioning of the textbox, how could I control that?

Comment: I suggest creating a default class like `.textbox` where you put the thing that is repeating in all other components like this `class="textbox textbox1"`: `.textbox {
  border: 3.5px solid black;
  width: 900px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: absolute;
}`

Comment: `<section class="textbox textbox1">` (the textbox1 is only accessable by the same page not the others) also I think you won't need to number them at this point just do `textbox-custum` inside <style> tag) the main shared file it will look like just 20 lines, and now is reduced, the custum code is inside <style> so other pages can't use it)

Comment: if you have any other problems, tell me I will solve them of course, have a nice coding/learning day! :)